# Excel:- Comparing 2 columns and then copying value in 3rd column

Tags: excel

I have data in 2 column where some data is available in Column A and Column B is blank and at some places data is available in column B where column A is blank.

I need to copy all the data in column C, so basically it should check if data is available in column A or B and then copy it to column C

It would be great help if someone can help on it

I need to copy all the data in column C, so basically it should check if data is available in column A or B and then copy it to column C

Comment: What if value is both in A and B columns, which one should be selected ? Meaning no empty cells in that row. Simple solution would be "=IF(ISBLANK(A2);B2;A2)"

Comment: Post few sample data as text table.

Comment: Data is present only in one of the column, there are no cases where data is present in both columns

Comment: Dummy data as below

Comment: Data1  Data2
ABCD 
EFGH 
IJKL 
       MKAL
       KAYM
JYAM 
       KYA
       KUMA
       KUTA
       RDS
YRSYS 
QEDW

Answer (score 0):

There is an excel if() function for this.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),B2,A2)
```